# Imagemagick crop while keeping size

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to crop the top 10 pixels of an image, but to keep the width

All exmaples I found look like

```
  convert rose: -crop 90x60-10-10  crop_all.gif
```

I need to supply the 90x60 so for the result size

How can I crop with something like `+0+10` and not supply a final size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this to chop 10px off the top edge:

```
convert rose: -chop 0x10 result.gif
```

Just for completeness, if you want to chop 10px off the bottom, do this:

```
convert rose: -gravity south -chop 0x10 result.gif
```

And to chop 10px off the left edge:

```
convert rose: -chop 10x result.gif
```

and 10px off the right edge:

```
convert rose: -gravity east -chop 10x result.gif
```

The reason you don't need to specify `-gravity` for top and left sides is that the default value for the `-gravity` setting is NorthWest.

Comment: `-crop` gives you the bit you cut, whereas `-chop` gives you what's left after the cut.